# Optimizing a subtraction

Tags: c, optimization

I am writing a program in C (where optimization is important) which uses unsigned char, and I have to sbstract these char from 255, i.e if I have an unsigned char x, I have to compute 255-x. Since this is simply inverting the 8 bits, is there a way to tell it to the compiler so this can be done faster ? Or does the CPU already know that and will just invert the bits so 255-x is the fastest way ?

Comment: You could take a look at the assembler that's produced to see if the compiler knows this optimization.  But note also that on any sane CPU, a subtraction and a bitwise inversion will take the same number of cycles.

Comment: BTW: the CPU knows nothing.

Comment: @wildplasser: That's something of an oversimplification, I think...

Comment: I wonder how many billion times this code will have to be executed before your optimisation delivers a measurable saving in execution time.

Comment: Give it a try and look which one is faster on your CPU.

Comment: Nowadays all trivial operations (add,substract,and,or,xor,complement) on trivial (char,int) data are faster than the bus can deliver the souce data to be acted upon and can write back the results back to memory.

Comment: @wildplasser: The operation speed versus the bus speed is not conclusive as there may be many in-register and in-cache operations per bus operation.

Comment: Not all architectures allow you to subtract from an immediate value, so the bitwise operation may save you a register. That said, what are the odds that the OP is the first person to think of this?

Comment: I know. But (in most cases?) this will only increase the pressure on the bus. Only very busy operations can benefit from marginal effect like these. (and only in corner cases, like scheduling problems caused by register pressure and such)

Answer (score 2):

Although as the comments say, this shouldn't be any faster, there is a bit inversion operator, `~`:

```
unsigned char c = ...;
c = ~c;
```

Answer (score 1):

If there is any performance difference, it will be due to extenuating circumstances, such as nuances of C involving expression evaluation, rather than due to the performance of subtraction versus bit inversion on modern processors. This question cannot be specifically answered without substantially more context.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the BITWISE NOT operator '~'?

For 8-bit unsigned integers, BITWISE NOT x = 255 - x

```
unsigned char x, u;
x = 12;
u = ~x;
printf (">> %d %d", u, x); // prints ">> 243 12"
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't waste optimization effort on the wrong things.

An infinite optimization of something that accounts for 1% of your total runtime will take infinite effort and yield a 1% total peformance improvement. A 10% improvement of something which accounts for 10% of your runtime is tremendously easier to achieve and yields the same benefit.

And don't forget that the compiler does its own optimizations, which will include the sort of simple substitution you're proposing if there's any benefit to be gained from them.

Don't optimize prematurely.

Write your code -- with an eye to efficiency of algorithms, but without trying to count instructions and cycles. Run the code under a performance profiler to find out where it's spending its time. Use that to guide where you should put effort into improving the code, either by changing the algorithm (usually a bigger win) or by fine-tuning the code. Repeat as needed.